# Get live currency exchange rates in Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, currency

Ok so I'm trying to build a live currency converter app using Cordova and for now just display the exchange as an alert upon opening the app. at the moment i'm not getting anything. i've found many tutorials in different languages but no javaScript that has a simple solution to my problem. any help would be great. thanks

```
getRate: function ()
    {
        $from   = 'USD'; 
        $to     = 'INR';
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('src', "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s="+ $from + $to +"=parseExchangeRate");
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    },

    parseExchangeRate: function(data)
    {
        var name = data.query.results.row.name;
        var rate = parseFloat(data.query.results.row.rate, 10);
        alert("Exchange rate " + name + " is " + rate);
    },
```

Comment: And what is the error in the developer console? The URL to the file looks totally wrong also.

Comment: @epascarello there are no errors it just dosnt display the alert I've tried amending it and the most i got was "object HTMLscriptElement"

Comment: @epascarello also the url works as i have manual tried it

Comment: Um, the url is... `http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?e=.csv&f=sl1d1t1&s=USDINR=parseExchangeRate` Looks wrong to me